# Could you recommend me any solved problem book about algebraic topology?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, book-recommendation

I'm having troubles with algrbraic topology and I would love to know if there is any solved problem book. I'm interested in the following topics:
1. Homotopy
2. Classification of compact topological surfaces
3. Riemann geometry on surfaces

Thanks, a strong hug.

Comment: Doesn't having all the problems solved take the fun out of it all?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely take a look at *Algebraic Topology: A First Course* by William Fulton. It's a fairly gentle introduction to the topic and includes the areas you mention, in particular topology of surfaces (chapters 17-18) and Riemann surfaces (chapters 19-21). It includes hints and answers to *some* of the problems at the back of the book.